# update time in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am newbie to php and I am doing an application in php using class and objects.Now I have a database where I have the fields for `Created_at` and `updated_at`. So can someone tell me how to get the created time and insert  `created` and `updated`  time in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NOW()` will help you out =)

You can also try out `CURDATE` and `CURTIME`

```
SELECT NOW(),CURDATE(),CURTIME()
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO the_table SET created_at = NOW()`

Comment: You might also find `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` useful: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$query_auto = "INSERT INTO tableName (Created_at, updated_at) VALUE (NOW(), NOW())";
mysql_query($query_auto) or die(mysql_error());
?>

<?php
$query_auto = "SELECT Created_at FROM tableName";
$result = mysql_query($query_auto) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```